# Matplotlib 3d plot_surface make edgecolors a function of z-value

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

How can we make `edgecolors` of a 3D surface plot a function of the z value?

The following will make the edgecolors uniformly black:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm, colors
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 20)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, 20)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = np.sin(x**2 + y**2)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, cmap=cm.coolwarm, edgecolors='k')
plt.show()
```

[image: Sample 3D surface plot]

How can we modify this example to:

1. Make the edgecolors white for z < 0.5 and black for z >= 0.5?
2. Make the edgecolors range smoothly from white when z=0 to black when z=1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's mainly a case of defining the appropriate colour maps. Then you can feed the data into `plot_surface()` twice - once for the face colours, and a second time just for the edges (edges will overlay the first plot, rendering the final plot).

[image]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm, colors

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 20)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, 20)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = np.sin(x**2 + y**2)

#Custom colour maps:
# Hard white-black transition
white_black = colors.ListedColormap(['white', 'black'])
# Linear transition
white_black_smooth = colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('Custom', ['white', 'black'])

#Plot using hard the first colourmap
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
#Colour the faces
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, facecolors=cm.coolwarm(z), shade=False)
#Overlay edge colours (facecolor alpha set to 0)
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, facecolors=white_black(z), linewidth=2.2, facecolor=(0,0,0,0))
plt.show()

#Plot using the second colourmap
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
#Colour the faces
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, facecolors=cm.coolwarm(z), shade=False)
#Overlay edge colours (facecolor alpha set to zero)
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, facecolors=white_black_smooth(z),
                linewidth=2.2, facecolor=(0,0,0,0), shade=False)
plt.show()
```